# Почему кнопка "заказать обратный звонок" стала ведущей?

Tags: html, css

Например при добавлении к ней `margin-top:50px;` сдвигается всё, включая саму кнопку:

```css
.header-up {
  height: 44px;
  font-family:Roboto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1200px;
}

body background {
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family:Roboto;
}

.header-up a{
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #ffffff;
}
    
#header1{
  display:inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
    
.header2-up {
  background-color:#285023;
}
    
.header-up img{
  margin-right: 10px;
}
    
#chelovek {
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-left: 1px #ffffff solid;
}
    
#login {
  float: right;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
    
#signin {
  display:inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 12px;
}
    
.headerlogo{
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
    
#logo{
  width:220px;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
    
#tovari {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #666666;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
    
#korzina{
  float:right;
  width: 101px;
}
    
#korzina2 {
  float:right;
  height:20px;
  color:#363636;
  text-decoration: none;
}
    
#summa {
  float: right;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -19px;
  color:#666;
}
    
#korzina-img{
  position:relative;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
    
#vremya{
  float:left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="header2-up">
       <div class="header-up">
          <img src="images/Shesterenka.png" id="sheterenka"><span id="header1"><a href="#">Служба поддержки</a></span>
          <img src="images/chelovek.png" id="chelovek"><span id="header1"><a href="#">Вакансии</a></span>
          <span id="signin"><a href="#">Зарегестрироваться</a></span>
          <span id="login"><a href="#">Войти</a></span>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="headerlogo">
       <div id="logo"><a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png"></a></div>
          <span id="tovari">Товары из Вьетнама<br/> от производителей</span>
          <span id="vremya"><span>Пн-Вс:10:00-21:00</span><br/><span>+7 (495) 989-72-68</span></span>
          <div id="zakazat"><a href="#"><img src="images/zakazat.png"></a></div>
          <div id="korzina"><span id="korzina-img"><img src="images/korzina.png" /></span>
          <span id="korzina-text"><a href="#" id="korzina2">Корзина<br/></a>
          <span id="summa">35 560 р.</span></span>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Не видно кнопки "заказать обратный звонок".

Comment: элемент margin-top сдвигает весь блок - редактируйте значение этого элемента, например, примените 5% или что-то подобное